# when document is loading, stop loading if this condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unbind, document-ready

When $(document).ready(function() stop if window is bigger than 350.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() > 350 ){
alert ("No!!! stop");
// I want to stop loading the page altogether if window is less than 350.
return false;
}
else if ($(window).width() < 350 ) {
alert ("Ok continue.")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please learn the difference between `Java` and `javascript` before you proceed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I don't see any mention of Java here? Did I miss something?

Comment: @TravisJ I edited it out.

Comment: My bad, I posted an auto generated tag by mistake. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop loading?"

Comment: Stop loading, maybe by emptying body if that's possible. Since you can empty a div.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function() executed after page is loaded.
you can do it if you put your javascript on top of your body, so it will execute before page is loaded

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   //your actions here
   //for example redirect to empty page that says stop your width is too large
   //another solution is to spam alerts() and if there is no alerts reload page to spam more
   //show page with javascript
   //$("body').html('STAPH')
</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Can i has like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just added

```
$("div").empty();
```

to just empty all divs if window is > 350.